# How to import a graphql file to typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql

I want to import a graphql file but I get an error

import typeDefs from "./schema/schema.graphql";

```
10 import typeDefs from "./schema/schema.graphql";
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    at createTSError (C:\Users\darkc\Desktop\New folder (2)\server\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:750:12)
    at reportTSError (C:\Users\darkc\Desktop\New folder (2)\server\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:754:19)
    at getOutput (C:\Users\darkc\Desktop\New folder (2)\server\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:941:36)
```

How to import a graphql file to typescript ?

Comment: You can't import it without babel or some kind of a transpiler/build tool. You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-import-graphql

Comment: I installed `babel-plugin-import-graphql` but still get the error

Answer (score 8):

You need to tell TypeScript what a `.graphql` file is in order for the import to work. This is not a file type that is supported OOTB in TypeScript. To do so, create a type definition file such as `graphql.d.ts` in your project. The file should contain the following declaration or somethings similar:

```
declare module '*.graphql' {
  import { DocumentNode } from 'graphql'
  const Schema: DocumentNode

  export = Schema
}
```

Personally, I prefer the shorthand extension `*.gql`. To do that, simply change the string value in the `declare module` expression.

Lastly, you will need to tell TypeScript to include your custom type definition in your TypeScript configuration `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/@types"],
  },
  "files": ["src/@types/graphql.d.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

For the record, I pulled this answer from the following article: https://dev.to/open-graphql/how-to-resolve-import-for-the-graphql-file-with-typescript-and-webpack-35lf. But you'll find that most solutions involve the same steps effectively.

Comment: Is there any way I can export import multiple queries from one single file(not folder).

Comment: Thanks for this accurate answer! For NextJS developers: you just need to create the above `graphql.d.ts` declaration file inside your `src` directory (for example: `src/types/graphql.d.ts`) because Next loads all `*.d.ts` files automatically.. no need to add to tsconfig.json if using NextJS 10+

Comment: missing out something with respect to webpack. where the webpack.config.js is located and how to create and configure and make it part of npm start?

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by [@CalebFaruki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1203355/caleb-faruki) (and already [here](https://dev.to/open-graphql/how-to-resolve-import-for-the-graphql-file-with-typescript-and-webpack-35lf)) works. But the only thing I needed is to add **`graphql.d.ts`** file (anywhere in my `src` directory):

```
declare module '*.graphql' {
  import { DocumentNode } from 'graphql'
  const Schema: DocumentNode
  export = Schema
}
```

Without `compilerOptions.typeRoots` and `files` in `tsconfig.json`.